# unique_ptr double deletion eror message

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

After compiling this piece of code 
I get error messages that indicate that there 
happens double deletion; my question is what exactly is 
wrong with this code? Where does the problem occur?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Manager;

class Interface {
protected:
  friend class InputListener;
  bool flag_;
};

class InputListener {
public:
  InputListener(std::shared_ptr<Interface> manager_ptr) {
    manager_ptr_ = std::move(manager_ptr);
    std::async(std::launch::async, &InputListener::Run, this);
  }

  void Run() {
    char c;
    std::cin >> c;
    manager_ptr_->flag_ = true;
  }

private:
  std::shared_ptr<Interface> manager_ptr_;
};

class Manager : public Interface {
public:
  Manager()
      : listener_ptr_{
            std::make_unique<InputListener>(std::shared_ptr<Manager>(this))} {}

  void Run() {
    while (true) {
      if (Interface::flag_)
        break;
    }
  }

private:
  std::unique_ptr<InputListener> listener_ptr_;
};

int main() {
  Manager m;
  m.Run();
  return 0;
}
```

Why does this code produce this error?
munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are passing a shared_ptr to 'this' during the constructor....

```cpp
  Manager()
      : listener_ptr_{
            std::make_unique<InputListener>(std::shared_ptr<Manager>(this))} {}
```

However 'this' is declared on the heap:

```cpp
  Manager m;
```

This will cause a problem when the dtor for the InputListener is called. Maybe consider changing manager_ptr_ to a weak_ptr if this is the intended usage for the class?

Answer (score 0):

You wrapped shared_ptr around a Manager that already has a path to destruction since it is instantiated on the stack.

Comment: Thanks for quick feedback! I have marked the other answer as correct because it was more elaborate.